# What does GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE mean for glTexImage2D?

Tags: opengl-es, textures

I want to load a byte array containing a texture in RGBA 8888 format.

[The OpenGL ES docs](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glTexImage2D.xml) offer 4 constants to use:  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, and GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1.

On [regular OpenGL](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter09.html), there is a value GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8 that meets my needs -- and the numbers are interpreted thus:

> For example, if internalFormat is GL_R3_G3_B2, you are asking that texels be 3 bits of red, 3 bits of green, and 2 bits of blue.

So GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8 must be 8 bits of R, 8 bits of G and 8 bits of B and 8 bits of A.

But what does GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE mean on the ES platform and how will it be interpretted?  (How many bits are R, G, B and A?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE should work with format GL_RGBA, giving 8 bits per component.

Comment: It seems that everyone says that type of thing -