# Improper colors displayed when loading 32-bit png using stb_image and using GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8 as glTexImage2D type parameter

Tags: opengl, png, textures, glteximage2d

I'm just learning how to texture in OpenGL and am a bit confused by some of the results I'm getting.

I'm using stb_image to load the following checkerboard png image:

[image: Black and white checkerboard image]

When I saved the png image I explicitly chose to save it as 32 bit. That would lead me to believe that each component (RGBA) would be stored as 8 bits for a total of 32 bits - the size of an unsigned int. However, using the following code:

```
unsigned char * texture_data = 
  stbi_load("resources/graphics-scene/tut/textures/checker.png", &w, &h, nullptr, 4);

// ...

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, w, h, 0,
  GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8,  texture_data);
```

yields:

[image: Black and white checkerboard in engine]

If I instead use GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE for the type parameter I get the proper results.

Also, just incase it helps, I also tried the following image:

[image: Colored checkerboard image]

which yields

[image: Colored checkerboard in engine]

GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE gives the correct result in this case as well.

I'm not sure if this is a case of me misunderstanding glTexImage2D or stb_image (does it convert loaded data to 8-bit? that would seem unlikely to me).

EDIT: I just finally found a related posted (had already searched some but had no luck). However the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4191875/2507444) confuses me. If that is the case - that the type parameter specifies how many bytes per **component** - then what exactly do things like GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE_3_3_2 and GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8 mean???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If that is the case - that the type parameter specifies how many bytes per component - then what exactly do things like GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE_3_3_2 and GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8 mean???

It does both, depending on what the actual type is.

If the [pixel transfer type](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_type) is just a data type, then it specifies the data size *per-component*. If it has numbers in it, then the type specifies the size of the data *per-pixel*; the numbers specify the individual component sizes *within* that data type.

`GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8` means that OpenGL will interpret each pixel as an unsigned integer. The first component will be the high 8 bits, the next will be the next 8 bits, and so forth.

***However***, where your problem is coming from is the fact that STB-image *does not* work with unsigned integers. Each pixel is written as 4 separate bytes, in RGBA order. Basically, it does this:

```
GLubyte arr[4] = {red, green, blue, alpha};
```

Now, that may *sound* like the same thing. But it isn't. The reason why has to do with [endian issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

When you do this in C/C++:

```
GLuint foo = 0;
foo |= (red << 24);
foo |= (green << 16);
foo |= (blue << 8);
foo |= (alpha << 0);
```

OpenGL's data types require `GLuint` to be an unsigned integer exactly 32-bits in size. And assuming that `red`, `green`, `blue`, and `alpha` are all `GLubyte`s (8-bit unsigned integers), C/C++ says that this will pack the `red` bits into the high 8-bit byte, the `green` into the next one, and so on. The C and C++ standards require this to work.

*However*, the C and C++ standards do *not* require this to work:

```
GLubyte *ptr = (GLubyte*)&foo;
ptr[0] == ((foo >> 24) & 0xFF);
```

That is, the first byte of memory pointed to by `foo` does not *have* to be the `red` component.

In little endian byte ordering, the low byte of a 32-bit integer is stored *first*, not last.

When OpenGL sees `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`, that means it will interpret those four bytes *exactly the way your CPU does*. So `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8` will do the equivalent of `foo` above. The first byte of memory it sees will be interpreted, on a little endian machine, as the *low byte*, not the high byte.

STB-image does not output `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8`. It treats each pixel as a 4-byte array, like `arr` above. Therefore, you must tell OpenGL that this is how your data is stored. So you say that each component is one byte. Which is what `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` does.